# $f(x)+f(y)\leq f(x)f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ maps from  $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0.1]$ such that $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\quad f(x)+f(y)\leq  f(x)f(y)$

1. Show that $f(0)=0$
2. deduce that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \quad f(x)=0$

indeed,
\begin{align}
f(0)+f(0)&\leq f(0)f(0) \\
2f(0)&\leq f(0)^{2}\\
f(0)^{2}-2f(0)&\geq 0\\
f(0)(f(0)-2)&\geq 0\\
f(0)\geq 0 &\mbox{ or } f(0)\geq 2\\
\end{align}
since $f(0)\in[0,1]$ then $f(0)\geq 0$
I'm stuck here

Comment: Use the fact that $f(0)\in[0,1]$ to get $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Is not an "or" is an "and"

Comment: You made a mistake in the last line. The conclusion is that $f(0)\leq 0$ or $f(0)\geq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

From $f(0)(f(0)-2)\ge 0$ we get that if $f(0)>0$ then $f(0)\ge 2.$ Now, since $0\le f(0)\le 1$ it is impossible to have $f(0)\ge 2.$ Thus it must be $f(0)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

$f(0)(f(0)-2)\geq 0$ implies $f(0)\leq 0$ or $f(0)\geq 0$, to see this consider $x^2-2x$, it is positive if $x\leq 0$ or $x\geq 2$  thus $f(0)=0$ since $f(0)\in [0,1]$.

Then $f(x+0)\leq f(0)f(x)=0$ and $f(x)\in [0,1]$ implies $f(x)=0$ also.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part is already done for many others.

For the second part

$2)$. make $y=0$ and then

$$f(x) \leq 0$$

but $f \in [0,1]$ so $f(x)=0$ for all $x$